# live USB and keyboard

Tags: release-loki, settings, keyboard

**live USB and keyboard**

I want to use Loki on a live USB flash drive to work on my Mac mini late 2012.

I successfully created a bootable Loki USB drive.

The net is accessible via WiFi (by the way, Ubuntu and Mint
can’t from a live USB!).

My two first problems  are with the keyboard :

- I need absolutely an Azerty keyboard (I’m french).
- I want to use my Apple aluminium *extended* keyboard.

Is there a way to add some files to the USB stick to solve this problem ?